# How to stream with ffmpeg in a separate process

Tags: ffmpeg, background-process

I need to stream with ffmpeg on Ubuntu. The streaming should be started from a bash script.

Currently, I call ffmpeg like this, as a part of subroutine in a bash script:

```
function startFFMpegEncoder () {
    echo "Starting Encoder..."

    killall -9 ffmpeg   

    ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i $CAM_PATH -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30 http://127.0.0.1:$FFMPEG_PORT/$VIDEO_PASSWORD/640/480/ &

    echo "Encoder started."
}
```

Here is an output  that is produced by this part of the script's execution:

```
Starting Encoder...
ffmpeg: no process found
ffmpeg version N-73895-g323ec6b Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 50.101 / 56. 50.101
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 25.100 /  5. 25.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

[1]+  Stopped                 ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i $CAM_PATH -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30 http://127.0.0.1:$FFMPEG_PORT/$VIDEO_PASSWORD/640/480/
Encoder started.
```

Why does the ffmpeg immediately gets stopped? Running ffmpeg in a separate terminal as a single command starts the broadcast for as long as there is an output trace in the terminal window.

Answer (score 6):

Probably it's trying to read stdin (ffmpeg actually takes interactive commands...). To disable that, ffmpeg has the `-nostdin` option—that should make it run in the background.

You could also consider `-loglevel fatal` or `-loglevel error` as well as a few other options to make it quieter (`-nostats`, etc.).

Comment: Even though these were an "on the point assumptions", actual solution is a bit different. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov you can post your own answer explaining the solution you went with, to help future visitors to the site.

Comment: Sure, just did that, you are just too quick)

Answer (score 4):

Redirecting stdin does the trick.

Use a command like: `ffmpeg ... > output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &`.

- `> output.log` Redirect stdout to output.log.
- `2>&1` Redirect stderr to stdout (so it ends up in the log file and not in the terminal).
- `< /dev/null` Redirect stdin (which ffmpeg thinks it needs) to `/dev/null` (which gives an empty stream).
- `&` has the process run in the background.

Answer (score 2):

As per [PHP example on ffmpeg site](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP), one should redirect input and both outputs to somewhere for ffmpeg to effectively run in the background:

```
ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i $CAM_PATH -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30 http://127.0.0.1:$FFMPEG_PORT/$VIDEO_PASSWORD/640/480/ -nostdin -nostats </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` bits do the trick.

Comment: Might want to send the output to a log file (or syslog) instead... Much easier to fix problems when the error messages aren't sent to /dev/null.